# Is the phonon thermal conductivity responsible for a large part of the total thermal conductivity in thermoelectric materials like Bismuth Telluride?

Tags: thermodynamics, semiconductor-physics

As far as I know, the phonon thermal conductivity is the largest contributor to the total thermal conductivity in semiconductors. Is this still true for compound semiconductors like bismuth telluride that have somewhat large electrical conductivities, or does the electron thermal conductivity become a larger contributor?